# Change dropdown option of a set of cells after changing another dropdown option

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some rows with tasks, and colums are days. All cells have a dropdown, the options are taken from another sheet, only 'Y' or 'N'. If the task is completed I chose Y in the dropdown.

I want to set all dropdown option in the same row as 'Y' if one of the same row is 'Y'. So If I have a row full of 'N' and I change one to 'Y' the rest should change to 'Y'. Same with 'N', if one cell is set as 'N' all the other cells of the same row should change to 'N'.

Tried some stuff but always end up with some kind of loop error.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code snippet:

Adjust the parameters (with comments in the code below) to match your specific scenario. Check also the attached gif to understand how I chose the specific parameters based on my example sheet.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const startRow = 2; // assuming header in row 1
  const startCol = 4; // dropdown starts in column D
  const endCol = 7; // dropdown ends in column G
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // select the name of your sheet
  const ss = e.source;
  const as = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const ar = e.range;
  const row = ar.getRow();
  const col = ar.getColumn();
  if (as.getName()==sheetName && row>=startRow && col>=startCol && col<=endCol){
    if(["Y","N"].includes(ar.getValue())){
      as.getRange(row,startCol,1,endCol-startCol+1)
      .setValues([(new Array(endCol-startCol+1))
      .fill(ar.getValue())])
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:**

[onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) is a trigger function. You are **not** supposed to execute it manually and if you do so you will actually get errors (because of the use of the event object). All you have to do is to **save** this code snippet to the script editor and then it will be triggered automatically upon edits.

### Output of code snippet:

[image]